# Proving limits of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Define a sequence $(s_n)$ by $s_1=1$ and $s_{n+1}= \frac{s_n^2+3}{2s_n}$ for $n \geq1$. If $s_n$ converges to $s$, then prove $s = \sqrt{3}$

Comment: For your question in the future, include what you have attempted. Welcome to maths stack exchange.

Comment: I will do this in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Guide:
$$s_{n+1} = \frac{s_n^2 + 3}{2s_n}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n+1} = \frac{(\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n)^2 + 3}{2(\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n)}$$

Think of how to introduce $s$ in the expression above and solve for $s$.